# Adding Multiple Pandas Columns to Sparse CSR Matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

so my question is based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927781/adding-pandas-columns-to-a-sparse-matrix).

I have Twitter data where I extracted unigram features and number of orthographies features such as excalamation mark, question mark, uppercase, and lowercase. I want to stack orthographies features into transformed unigram feature. Here is my code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(tweet_df[['tweets', 'exclamation', 'question', 'uppercase', 'lowercase']], tweet_df['class'], stratify=tweet_df['class'],
                                 test_size = 0.2, random_state=0)

count_vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1))
X_train_gram = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train['tweets'])

tfidf = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_gram = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train_gram)

X_train_gram = hstack((X_train_gram,np.array(X_train['exclamation'])[:,None]))
```

This worked, however I can't find a way to incorporate the rest of columns (question, uppercase, lowercase) into the stack in one line of code. Here is the failed try:

```
X_train_gram = hstack((X_train_gram,np.array(list(X_train['exclamation'], X_train['question'], X_train['uppercase'], X_train['lowercase']))[:,None])) #list expected at most 1 arguments, got 4

X_train_gram = hstack((X_train_gram,np.array(X_train[['exclamation', 'question', 'uppercase', 'lowercase']])[:,None])) #expected dimension <= 2 array or matrix

X_train_gram = hstack((X_train_gram,np.array(X_train[['exclamation', 'question', 'uppercase', 'lowercase']].values)[:,None])) #expected dimension <= 2 array or matrix
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems with list syntax and `sparse.coo_matrix` creation.

```
np.array(X_train['exclamation'])[:,None])
```

`Series` to array is 1d, with None, becomes (n,1)

```
np.array(list(X_train['exclamation'], X_train['question'], X_train['uppercase'], X_train['lowercase']))[:,None]
```

That's not valid list syntax:

```
In [327]: list(1,2,3,4)                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-327-e06d60ac583e> in <module>
----> 1 list(1,2,3,4)

TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (4 given)
```

next:

```
np.array(X_train[['exclamation', 'question', 'uppercase', 'lowercase']])[:,None])
```

With multiple columns, we get a DataFrame; which makes a 2d array; add the `None`, and get a 3d array:

```
In [328]: np.ones((2,3))[:,None].shape                                          
Out[328]: (2, 1, 3)
```

Can't make a `coo` matrix from a 3d array.  Adding `values` doesn't change things.  `np.array(dataframe)` is the same as `dataframe.values`.

```
np.array(X_train[['exclamation', 'question', 'uppercase', 'lowercase']].values)[:,None]
```

This has a chance of working:

```
hstack((X_train_gram, np.array(X_train[['exclamation', 'question', 'uppercase', 'lowercase']].values))
```

though I'd suggest writing

```
arr = np.array(X_train[['exclamation', 'question', 'uppercase', 'lowercase']].values
M = sparse.coo_matrix(arr)
sparse.hstack(( X_train_gram, M))
```

It's more readable, and should be easier to debug if there are problems.